# Bootstrap Typeahead after ajax call

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I am using typeahead for listing cities depend on country. I have to use ajax for this typeahead does not work with ajax call. Anyone have an idea?
 Here is my codes:

```
$("#usercity").typeahead({
    source:function(query,process){
    return $.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"choosecity.php",
data:"country="+val,
success:function(a){
return process(a);
}
})
    }
});
```

What will be print of "choosecity.php" also?
I used this for an example:

```
echo "['City1','City2']";
```

But it does not work at all..

Comment: there is a error in your javascript... U missed ; in closed ajax function

Comment: You have a missing semicolon at your 9th line...

Answer (score 0):

there is a error in your javascript... U missed ; in closed ajax function

```
   $("#usercity").typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
            return $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "choosecity.php",
                data: "country=" + val,
                success: function (a) {
                    return process(a);
                }
            }); /* U ; missed it*/
        }
    });
```